# How can I redirect discord.py's console output into a channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The title is self-explanatory. I am trying to send the output that the bot would normally send to the console to a channel.

Comment: do you mean sending any errors to the channel? discord.py does not output anything to the console unless you `print()` it.

Answer (score 2):

you use "message.channel.send()" for sending to the currently active channel (the channel which the most recent message came from). There is no special way to do this, so you just implement it yourself.